# How to implement a Meta Path Importer on Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I'm struggling to refactor some working import-hook-functionality that served us very well on Python 2 the last years... And honestly I wonder if something is **broken** in Python 3? But I'm unable to see any reports of that around so confidence in doing something wrong myself is still stronger! Ok. Code:

Here is a cooked down version for **Python 3** with `PathFinder` from `importlib.machinery`:

```
import sys
from importlib.machinery import PathFinder


class MyImporter(PathFinder):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def find_spec(self, fullname, path=None, target=None):
        print('MyImporter %s find_spec fullname: %s' % (self.name, fullname))
        return super(MyImporter, self).find_spec(fullname, path, target)


sys.meta_path.insert(0, MyImporter('BEFORE'))
sys.meta_path.append(MyImporter('AFTER'))
print('sys.meta_path:', sys.meta_path)

# import an example module
import json
print(json)
```

So you see: I insert an instance of the class right in front and one at the end of `sys.meta_path`.  Turns out **ONLY** the first one triggers! I never see any calls to the last one. That was different in **Python 2**!

Looking at the implementation in [six](https://github.com/benjaminp/six/blob/master/six.py#L164) I thought, well **THEY** need to know how to do this properly! ...  I don't see this working either! When I try to step in there or just put some prints... Nada!

**After all:**
IF I actually put my Importer first in the `sys.meta_path` list, trigger on certain import and patch my module (which all works fine) It **still** gets overridden by the other importers in the list!
* How can I prevent that?
* Do I need to do that? It seems dirty!

Comment: It looks to me like the first `PathFinder` is triggered right away, then the module is imported, so the second `PathFinder` doesn't need to run.

Comment: But who is deciding that? And how to prevent that? And If you remove the insert: It STILL doesn't trigger the last one. And like in six: Theirs doens't trigger as well ...

Comment: When Python looks for a module, it first checks each element of `sys.meta_path` in order until it finds the module path, then stops and returns it. The last element of `meta_path` should only be checked if the module you are looking for can't be found elsewhere in the path. I don't why `six` appends its importer to the end of the list, but the [documentation for `importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#setting-up-an-importer) mentions the importance of ordering imports in a comment: "[m]ake sure to put the finder in the proper location in the list in terms of priority."

Comment: Oh. Yeah I even forgot to mention that: **If** I actually do that, import and modify my wanted module It gets overridden by the standard importer and my modifications are gone again.

Comment: But nice docs link! I didn't see that yet! 

Comment: If you're trying to use a modified version of an existing module, is there any reason you can't just insert it into `sys.modules` at the beginning of the program?

Comment: It's not about a single module. We put an override system in place to make the same code work in different environments and still have subtle changes.

Comment: It is true tho that IF an import was not successful by the other importers in `sys.meta_path` it ends up in my appended importer!
BUT: When prepended and my import returns successfully and ends up in `sys.modules` why is it overridden then?!?!?! :(

Answer (score 0):

I have been heavily studying the meta_path in Python3.8

The entire import mechanism has been moved from C to Python and manifests itself as sys.meta_path which contains 3 importers. The Python import machinery is cleverly stupid. i.e. uncomplex.

While the source code of the entire python import is to be found in importlib/

meta_path[1] pulls the importer from frozen something: bytecode=?

underscore import is still the central hook called when you "import mymod"

--import--() first checks if the module has already been imported in which case it retrieves it from sys.modules

if that doesn't work it calls find_spec() on each "spec finder" in meta_path.
If the "spec finder" is successful it return a "spec" needed by the next stage

If none of them find it, import fails

sys.meta_path is an array of "spec finders"

0: is the builtin spec finder: (sys, _sre)

1: is the frozen import lib: It imports the importer (importlib)

2: is the path finder and it finds both library modules: (os, re, inspect)
and your application modules based on sys.path

So regarding the question above, it shouldn't be happening. If your spec finder is first in the meta_path and it returns a valid spec then the module is found, and remaining entries in sys.meta_path won't even be asked.